# HP PROBOOK over heating

Tags: hp, overheating, fan

MY hp probook 4530's fan doesnt seem to be turning up when it needs to. Im currently running the latest version of ubuntu aka 13.04. I dont play games much and my hp probook only has intel 3000 graphics. All the drivers seem to be in order. However my fan is not turning up when needed. I am new to linux as well. Now I have to install a fan speed control application. if someone could help me out that would be great. I even attempted modifying the grub file. I added the line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force i915.i915_enable_rc6=1 i915.lvds_downclock=1" to no avail. I must switch computers now because my laptop is getting to hot. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: fans are controlled by the bios/hardware, so you'll have to consult HP.

Answer (score 0):

We have the same laptop model:)I love my laptop.

Go to your bios-->configuration-->devices
And turn off switchable graphics.This will completely shut down your radeon gpu and you will only use the integrated intel gpu.If you dualboot with windows you should turn it on again every time you want to boot into windows.The problem is basically in the open source drivers.

I know this is just a fix and not a real solution,but...
Let's hope this get's fixed in Ubuntu 13.10 which will be released in 6 days.